# android eclipse sdk loction

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a sdk location problem.

C:\android_app\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140624\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140624\sdk

This location doesn't work. and actually This location doesn't exist.

I have the sdk location that is C:\android_app\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\sdk

what I should do?

Comment: what do you mean by "this location doesn't work"

Answer (score 0):

You should create the location that doesn't exist by making folders & within that copy the SDK contents.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I install latest adt_bunble. then the error is gone.